# Process Start() stuck

Tags: c#, process

I use this following code :

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start(); // stuck here

using (StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput)
{
    if (writer.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        // write some commands
    }
}
```

When I call `process.Start()` nothing appends, the program stop his progress.
I don't understand why, thanks for help.

Edit : When I press a key in the console, the program continue...

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Stuck without errors? or the process is started but you don't know what's happening?

Comment: Stuck without errors yes, the program is still active but stucked..

Comment: When I press a key in the console, the program continue...

Comment: Tried your code in a console program and it works without being stucked

Comment: I have tried more, sometimes it works, sometimes not...
In Release Mode it always works... strange..